# Como printar o author do post em jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Estou tentando printar o autor do post quando rodo o loop para listar os posts na index, porém não conseguindo fazer isso.

Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Segue o código:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}    
    {% assign author = site.authors[post.author] %}
    {{author.name}} // não printa nada aqui 
{% endfor %}
```

_config.yml:

```
authors:
  bruno_folle:
    name: Bruno Folle
```

front matter:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Welcome to Jekyll!"
date:   2018-09-17 12:58:34 +0200
categories: jekyll update
author: bruno_folle
---
```

Comment: Você atribui algum autor no cabeçalho front matter dos posts?

Comment: atribui sim, vou editar colocando o front matter. Esqueci dele

Comment: Aparentemente seria só usar `page.author`. Segundo [a documentação](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables) a variável `author` não é disponibilizada automaticamente, mas todas as variáveis do front matter são expostas na variável `page`

Comment: Então ao invés de usar post.author eu uso page.author?

Comment: Precisa testar, mas pela documentação é isso mesmo

Comment: Testei e nada também